# Receive an error unable to find method testImplementation() when trying to deploy my gradle app to heroku

Tags: gradle, heroku

I have tried the solutions recommended by many in SO but none has worked so far. I am new to heroku, just created an account and followed their instructions on how to deploy my app on it. So far every attempt has failed, and I don't know how to resolve it.

```
plugins {
      id 'application'
      id 'jacoco'
}

repositories {
      jcenter()
}

dependencies {
      def junitVer = '5.6.2'
      implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '29.0-jre'
      implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
      implementation group: 'net.sf.oval', name: 'oval', version: '2.1.6'
      testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: junitVer
      testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitVer
      testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
      testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.+'
      testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-swing-junit', version: '3.+'
      def joobyVer = '1.6.8'
      implementation group: 'org.jooby', name: 'jooby-netty', version: joobyVer
      implementation group: 'org.jooby', name: 'jooby-gson', version: joobyVer
      implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.5'
      implementation group:'org.bouncycastle', name:'bcprov-jdk15on', version:'1.66'
}
```

[Error Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQOQr.png)

Thank you, if anyone has any idea how to solve this issue.